# Is it possible to install a non certificate on a android phone remotely?

Tags: android

In a Samsung Galaxy S series, I've noticed a notification saying that your network might have been watched and is not safe. Is it possible for someone to remotely install a certificate and eavesdropping on communications? What if he controls the mobile communication network ISP? Communications are encrypted, though a man in the middle attack is possible if an invalid cert is installed in the trusted section of the phone. Is that correct?

Comment: No. Just being able to control the flow of communication does not mean that they have control over your device.

Comment: That notification on Android is usually displayed when a VPN is on and using a certificate that does not chain to a default CA.

Comment: I would guess that the notification refers to unencrypted connections which can be watched.